# Algorithm for creating infinite terrain/landscape/surface?

Tags: algorithm

Does any have an algorithm for creating infinite terrain/landscape/surface?

Constraints

1. The algorithm should start by a random seed
2. The algorithm should be one to one, (the same seed gives the same result)
3. Other input parameter are allowed as long as 2 is fulfilled
4. The algorithm may output a 2d map
5. It suppose to create only surface with varying height (mountains), not three, ocean etc.
6. I’m looking for an algorithm and not a software.
7. It should be fast

None of other related questions in here answers this question.
If anything is unclear please let me know!

Comment: Planet, being a spehere (roughly) can not have an infinite surface.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

Comment: Has anyone tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_landscape

Comment: From this very page: `There are many fractal procedures (such as Perlin noise) ` - so yes

Comment: It maybe a planet in game terms, but mathematically it is a plane.

Comment: Yes it is! it can be put on any surface like a texture.

Comment: Just don't call it 'a planet'. The word comes from Greek 'wanderer' and the fact that planets (in contrast to stars) chenge their position on the sky. Now an infinite plane wwould certainly look interesting in the night sky, but it wouldn't wander much. :D

Comment: Just FYI, Perlin noise by itself is not a fractal noise - see the first image in this article for an example of Perlin noise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise (note how it has rather uniform "bumps", and not the noisy ones which result from adding higher-frequency noise to this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest something like Perlin noise, I've used it before for something like you're describing above, and it fits the bill. Check out this [Example](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial4.html) and you can see the sort of output you would expect from the noise generator.Here is a link to algorithm p-code too.

[http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20160530124230/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)

Comment: The above is mislabeled - it is fractal noise (Perlin noise is not a type of fractal noise), generated via value noise (and Perlin noise is not a type of value noise - it is gradient noise). Not that it isn't useful though.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said perlin noise is a possibility. [Gpugems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html) has a nice capter about procedual generation using (IIRC, it has been some time since I read this) 3D Perlin noise.

Of course there are other methods too, e.g. [Vterrain.org](http://vterrain.org/Elevation/Artificial/) might be worth a look.